# Is there a ROS package manager for Indigo?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to port [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/articulation_tutorials/Tutorials/ArticulationWebcamDemo/) to ROS Indigo using the source from [this repository](https://github.com/tum-vision/articulation), however there are some packages missing. Currently I am compiling the packages one-by-one following [these instructions](http://answers.ros.org/question/115261/how-to-install-an-individual-package-in-ros-hydro/?answer=115386#post-id-115386), but that becomes tedious very quickly. Am I overlooking a simpler way of accomplishing that? It seems the dependency information from the [stack.xml](https://github.com/tum-vision/articulation/blob/master/stack.xml) files is completely ignored this way. Am I overlooking something?

Since I am not on Linux, it seems I don't have access to the packages available via `sudo apt-get install ros-[package-name]`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238657/is-there-a-ros-package-manager-for-indigo?/) by [rauschen](https://answers.ros.org/users/27368/rauschen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS provides three tools for this process: [rosinstall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator), [wstool](http://wiki.ros.org/wstool) and [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep)

`rosinstall_generator` and `wstool` work together to manage a source checkout of multiple packages. `wstool` uses a workspace file with a list of package directories and remote repository URLs to check out each package into the specified directory, and eep the source checkout up to date. `rosinstall_generator` can create a workspace file that satisfies all of the dependencies for a specific package or set of packages.

`rosdep` fills the gaps between ROS packages and the system, by using your system's package manager to install dependencies on system packages.

The typical workflow for these three tools is something like:

- Source your existing ROS environment; cd into your workspace directory.
- For the new package that you want to install, add that package and any missing dependencies to your workspace file:

  `rosinstall_generator rviz --deps --exclude RPP | wstool merge -t src -` (change `rviz` to whichever package you want to install)
- Update your workspace from the updated workspace file:

  `wstool update -t src` (add -jN to run N downloads in parallel)
- Install any missing system dependencies:

  `rosdep install --from-paths src -i`
- Build your workspace:

  `catkin_make`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0